# Best output type and encoding practices for __repr__() functions?

Tags: python, encoding, ascii, repr

Lately, I've had lots of trouble with `__repr__()`, `format()`, and encodings.  **Should the output of `__repr__()` be encoded or be a unicode string?**  Is there a best encoding for the result of `__repr__()` in Python?  What I want to output does have non-ASCII characters.

I use Python 2.x, and want to write code that can easily be adapted to Python 3.  The program thus uses

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function  # The 'Hello' literal represents a Unicode object
```

Here are some additional problems that have been bothering me, and I'm looking for a solution that solves them:

1. Printing to an UTF-8 terminal should work (I have `sys.stdout.encoding` set to `UTF-8`, but it would be best if other cases worked too).
2. Piping the output to a file (encoded in UTF-8) should work (in this case, `sys.stdout.encoding` is `None`).
3. My code for many `__repr__()` functions currently has many `return ….encode('utf-8')`, and that's heavy.  Is there anything robust and lighter?
4. In some cases, I even have ugly beasts like `return ('<{}>'.format(repr(x).decode('utf-8'))).encode('utf-8')`, i.e., the representation of objects is decoded, put into a formatting string, and then re-encoded.  I would like to avoid such convoluted transformations.

What would you recommend to do in order to write simple `__repr__()` functions that behave nicely with respect to these encoding questions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Python2, `__repr__` (and `__str__`) must return a string object, not a
unicode object. In Python3, the situation is reversed, `__repr__` and `__str__`
must return unicode objects, not byte (née string) objects:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return u'\N{WHITE SMILING FACE}' 

class Bar(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return u'\N{WHITE SMILING FACE}'.encode('utf8')

repr(Bar())
# ☺
repr(Foo())
# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u263a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In Python2, you don't really have a choice. You have to pick an encoding for the
return value of `__repr__`.

By the way, have you read the [PrintFails wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails)? It may not directly answer
your other questions, but I did find it helpful in illuminating why certain
errors occur.

---

When using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`,

```
'<{}>'.format(repr(x).decode('utf-8'))).encode('utf-8')
```

can be more simply written as

```
str('<{}>').format(repr(x))
```

assuming `str` encodes to `utf-8` on your system.

Without `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, the expression can be written as:

```
'<{}>'.format(repr(x))
```

Comment: It would be nice if the documentation mentioned this :) (http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization does not)…  Anyway… you would say that the approach in point 4 in the question is cumbersome but necessary, right?

Comment: EOL: Assuming Python2, `repr(x)` must return an encoded string. If it was encoded with utf-8, then `repr(x).decode('utf8').encode('utf8')` should not be necessary.
If `repr(x)` is encoded with some other encoding, `repr(x).decode('utf8')` will either fail (with UnicodeDecodeError) or produce bogus results, or maybe decode correctly by lucky happenstance. So, AFAIK, `repr(x).decode('utf8').encode('utf8')`
should never be necessary. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @EOL, **The return value must be a string object.** is how the reference manual page you point to expresses the constraint that the return value must be an instance of `str` (a unicode object would not be "a string object").  `repr` is _normally_ expected to return ascii only (thing of `repr(uo)` for all unicode objects, for example: even _that_ returns ascii only -- I think no built-in or standard library type behaves otherwise) but strictly speaking that is not a language constraint, so it's not the reference manual's business.  Proposed docs patches are always welcome, btw!-)

Comment: @Alex: Thank you for the comments.  I guess that my confusion comes from the fact that one also says "Unicode string", in Python 2.x: that's why I was wondering whether `__repr__()` could also return a *Unicode* string…  I have been thinking of submitting doc patches. :)

Comment: @~unutbu: I should have put parentheses in the example, which differs from what you put in the comment: the decoded object is put *into a formatting string* before encoding.  I updated the original question.

Comment: @EOL, yes, I find string-related terminology ("string", "unicode string", "raw string", ...) unfortunately at risk of ambiguity in common discourse -- I _try_ to always use rigorously non-ambiguous terms such as "str instance", "unicode object", "rawstring _literal_ ", and so forth, but sometimes such rigorous terminology feels stilted in non-formal contexts. In the Language Reference, the only occurrences of the unfortunate "unicode string" are in a single paragraph in 2.4.1 (literals): s/string/object/ there and "string" becomes unambiguous *in the Language Reference* (where it matters).

Comment: It's also possible that the Language Reference is _deliberately_ ambiguous because it's **not** supposed to be a Reference for **CPython** only, but for _all_ conforming Python implementations: in Jython and IronPython, which we're very keen to consider fully conforming implementations, **all** strings are Unicode (and it would be costly and totally against their respective platforms to make things otherwise).  Maybe we do need a supplemental **CPython** implementation-specific reference, as an _addition_ to the implementation-neutral **Language** one.

Comment: @~unutbu: since `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is in force, '<{}>' *is* a Unicode string.  So, it looks again like you're confirming that what I'm doing is correct; it's good to get such a confirmation.  I'll mark your question as accepted if you can remove the part that assumes that '<{}>' is a str.

Comment: @EOL: Ah, I forgot about `unicode_literals`. Yes, I agree with you then. If you didn't have `unicode_literals` turned on, however, you could write `'<{}>'.format(repr(x))` instead of `'<{}>'.format(repr(x).decode('utf-8'))).encode('utf-8')`. Are you sure that `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is worth it?

Comment: Of course, `str('<{}>').format(repr(x))` would also work...
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809796/any-gotchas-using-unicode-literals-in-python-2-6

Comment: @~unutbu: Unicode with Python 2.x *is* tricky: `'<{}>'.format(repr(x))` does *not* work when you have bytes with value > 127 in the representation (because the literal creates a Unicode object)!  Thank you for the `str(…).format()` suggestion.  As for the `from __future__`, I like the fact that string literals are Unicode objects, because these objects correspond to Python 3's strings (one of the goals is to prepare the transition to Python 3).

Comment: @EOL: I'm not sure that `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is helping you prepare for Python3. Think about what your code should look like in Python3. It would just be `'<{}>'.format(repr(x))`. Anything you write that deviates from that, even `str('<{}>').format(repr(x))`, is just cruft that will have to be fixed during the transition. Are you sure that `'<{}>'.format(repr(x))` does not work if you turn off `unicode_literals`?

Comment: @~unutbu: good point, about the simpler code when not using `unicode_literals`.  I'll turn it off (in which case the simpler code does indeed work).  If you can remove the part with "may be incorrect" (which refers to a different situation than that of the question, which assumed Unicode litterals), I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

I think a decorator can manage `__repr__` incompatibilities in a sane way. Here's what i use:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
import sys

def force_encoded_string_output(func):

    if sys.version_info.major < 3:

        def _func(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs).encode(sys.stdout.encoding or 'utf-8')

        return _func

    else:
        return func


class MyDummyClass(object):

    @force_encoded_string_output
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'My Dummy Class! \N{WHITE SMILING FACE}'
```

Comment: Nice decorator; I modified it, though, so that `_func` is not defined when it is not needed. So, `__repr__` in Python 2 can apparently return a Unicode string, according to your code (maybe because of `unicode_literals`?). This clashes with unutbu answer… I find the documentation ambiguous, on this (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__, http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-14). I would be interested in any reference information on this, just to be sure that no unforeseen problems can arise from having `__repr__` return a Unicode string.

Comment: @EOL *So, `__repr__` in Python 2 can apparently return a Unicode string (...)* Why do you think so?

Comment: Good catch, my bad. I will delete my earlier comment, as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I use a function like the following:

```
def stdout_encode(u, default='UTF8'):
    if sys.stdout.encoding:
        return u.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
    return u.encode(default)
```

Then my `__repr__` functions look like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return stdout_encode(u'<MyClass {0} {1}>'.format(self.abcd, self.efgh))
```