# How to make __repr__ to return unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, repr

I call a `__repr__()` function on object `x` as follows:

`val = x.__repr__()`

and then I want to store `val` string to `SQLite` database. The problem is
that `val` should be unicode.

I tried this with no success:

`val = x.__repr__().encode("utf-8")`

and

`val = unicode(x.__repr__())`

Do you know how to correct this?

I'm using `Python 2.7.2`

Comment: "How to make `__repr__` to return an unicode string" - By installing Python 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`repr(x).decode("utf-8")` and `unicode(repr(x), "utf-8")` should work.

Answer (score 16):

The representation of an object should not be Unicode. Define the `__unicode__` method and pass the object to `unicode()`.

Comment: OK, but here the object was not mine but from a library.

Comment: Could you explain why the representation of an object is not supposed to be unicode ? Thanks

Comment: @Joucks: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627793/best-output-type-and-encoding-practices-for-repr-functions

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, because I was pulling the text out of a list using repr.

```
b =['text\xe2\x84\xa2', 'text2']  ## \xe2\x84\xa2 is the TM symbol
a = repr(b[0])
c = unicode(a, "utf-8")
print c

>>> 
'text\xe2\x84\xa2'
```

I finally tried join to get the text out of the list instead

```
b =['text\xe2\x84\xa2', 'text2']  ## \xe2\x84\xa2 is the TM symbol
a = ''.join(b[0])
c = unicode(a, "utf-8")
print c

>>> 
text™
```

Now it works!!!!

I tried several different ways.  Each time I used repr with the unicode function it did not work.  I have to use join or declare the text like in variable e below.

```
b =['text\xe2\x84\xa2', 'text2']  ## \xe2\x84\xa2 is the TM symbol
a = ''.join(b[0])
c = unicode(repr(a), "utf-8")
d = repr(a).decode("utf-8")
e = "text\xe2\x84\xa2"
f = unicode(e, "utf-8")
g = unicode(repr(e), "utf-8")
h = repr(e).decode("utf-8")
i = unicode(a, "utf-8")
j = unicode(''.join(e), "utf-8")
print c
print d
print e
print f
print g
print h
print i
print j

*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
'text\xe2\x84\xa2'
'text\xe2\x84\xa2'
textâ„¢
text™
'text\xe2\x84\xa2'
'text\xe2\x84\xa2'
text™
text™
>>>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, you can define two methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Person info <name={0}>".format(self.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Person(u"皮特")
    print A
```

In Python3, just define `__repr__` will be ok:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return u"Person info <name={0}>".format(self.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Person(u"皮特")
    print(A)
```