# unicode_literals and type()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, six-python

I'm having problems supporting python2 and python3 on a `type()` call. This demonstrates the problem:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

name='FooClass'
type(name, (dict,), {})
```

No problem on python3, but on python2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    type(name, (dict,), {})
TypeError: type() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

This is related to [Any gotchas using unicode_literals in Python 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809796/any-gotchas-using-unicode-literals-in-python-2-6). In that question, someone recommends typecasting to a bytestring, so naively I thought about using [`six.b()`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.b):

> A “fake” bytes literal. data should always be a normal string literal.
>   In Python 2, b() returns a 8-bit string. In Python 3, data is encoded
>   with the latin-1 encoding to bytes.

So it looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import six

name='FooClass'
type(six.b(name), (dict,), {})
```

But it fails on both python2 and python3:

```
$ python2 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    type(six.b(name), (dict,), {})
TypeError: type() argument 1 must be string, not unicode

$ python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    type(six.b(name), (dict,), {})
TypeError: type() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

So it seems that **really**, `type()` wants a python2 str which is a python3 bytestring on python2, but it wants a python3 str which is a python2 unicode string on python3.

What do you think ?

Is there something I don't understand ?

Or is there a real incompatibility with `type()` on python 2 and 3 ?

Isn't there *any* way to have the same `type()` call supporting both 2 and 3 ?

Shouldn't a tool like `six` provide a wrapper around `type()` in that case ?

Comment: Thanks, that works, I was sure I had tested it though ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`six.b` is written under the assumption that you won't use `unicode_literals` (and that you'll pass a string literal to it, as the documentation states), so the Python 2 implementation is just `def b(s): return s` as a Python 2 string literal is already a byte string.

Either don't use `unicode_literals` in this module, or use (as a comment suggests) `str(name)`. In Python 3, that is a no-op. In Python 2, it silently converts the unicode string to a byte string (assuming some encoding that I can't be bothered to remember, but it's a superset of ASCII so you should be fine).