# Escaping unicode string using \u

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string like `"vÃ¡lido"` . Usually python can convert this to hex based easily on the command prompt and this would become `'v\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1lido'`

But I want to use `\u` for the unicode codepoints, so I want the output like `"v\u00c2\u00a1lido"`

So basically the input should be `"vÃ¡lido"` and the output should be `"v\u00c2\u00a1lido"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the preferred way to include unicode in python source files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062544/whats-the-preferred-way-to-include-unicode-in-python-source-files)

Comment: I am not sure how this is the duplicate. If you look at the example above, some characters in the inputs strings are normal ascii characters and so is the case in the output too.

Comment: I didn't really mean it's a duplicate, but you will certainly find your answers in the post

Answer (score 1):

`\u` only works in Unicode strings; start your string literal with `u`:

```
u"v\u00c2\u00a1lido"
```

Demo:

```
>>> u"v\u00c2\u00a1lido"
u'v\xc2\xa1lido'
>>> print u"v\u00c2\u00a1lido"
vÂ¡lido
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `json.dumps` is what you need:

```
>>> s="vÃ¡lido"
>>> s
'v\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1lido'
>>> json.dumps(s)
'"v\\u00c3\\u00a1lido"'
>>> print json.dumps(s)
"v\u00c3\u00a1lido"
```

Maybe it's too late for the OP, but hope it can help guys who are trying to solve the same problem.