# Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report. ascii

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openerp-7, libreoffice, aeroolib

I used aeroo report for generating xls report in openerp 7, I created ods file containing data as input file, and xls as output
[image]

I used python function return arabic string,

```
    def _test(self, data):
    res=[]
    for item in data :
        month_move=datetime.strptime(str(item.date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').year
        if month_move == date.today().year:
            res.append(item)
    return res,'الاتبللا'
```

and i have some date is an arabic letter, when i tried to print the report, i got this error msg:

```
Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report. ascii
```

[image]
I got that error if i use the function, but if i dont used it, the report generate correctly,

I used Genshi package version 6.0, and libreoffice version 5.1, and openerp version 7 , and python version 2.7

forgive me for my bad english, and thank an advence
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an encoding problem with the second return argument:

> 'الاتبللا'

You did not prefix the string with `u`, which is needed in Python 2.  Even better, [import unicode_literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809796/any-gotchas-using-unicode-literals-in-python-2-6).