# Encoding Unicode in the Dictionary Key to Japanese

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I just started working on text clustering in Japanese through Python2. However, when I created the dictionary based on these Japanese words/terms, the dictionary keys become unicode instead of Japanese. The codes are as follows:

```
# load data
allWrdMat10 = pd.read_csv("../../data/allWrdMat10.csv.gz", 
encoding='CP932') 


## Set X as CSR Sparse Matrix
X = np.array(allWrdMat10)
X = sp.csr_matrix(X)

## create dictionary
dict_index = {t:i for i,t in enumerate(allWrdMat10.columns)}

freqrank = np.array(dict_index.values()).argsort()
X_transform = X[:, freqrank < 1000].transpose().toarray()
```

The results of `allWrdMat10.columns` are still Japanese as follows:

```
Index([u'?', u'．', u'・', u'％', u'０', u'１', u'１０月', u'１１月', u'１２
月', u'１つ',
...
u'瀋陽', u'疆', u'盧', u'籠', u'絆', u'胚', u'諫早', u'趙', u'鉉', u'鎔
基'],dtype='object', length=8655)
```

However, the results of `dict_index.keys()` are as:

```
[u'\u77ed\u9283',
 u'\u5efa\u3066',
 u'\u4f0a',
 u'\u5e73\u5b89',
 u'\u6025\u9a30',
 u'\u897f\u65e5\u672c',
 u'\u5e03\u9663',
 ...]
```

Is there any way I can keep the Japanese words/terms in the dictionary keys? Or is there any way I can convert the unicodes back to Japanese words/terms? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not prefix the string with u, which is needed in Python 2. Even better, 
[unicode_literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809796/any-gotchas-using-unicode-literals-in-python-2-6)
   `import unicode_literals`

Comment: Thank you. @KHELILI Hamza, could you please provide more details regarding the process?

Comment: @tzu this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809796/any-gotchas-using-unicode-literals-in-python-2-6

Comment: @tzu if your code is working good, you don't forget to accept my answer please

Answer (score 1):

When you ask the interpreter for the value of an expression it computes the value and then outputs its `repr()`. The `print` statement (v2) or function (v3) uses the `str()` of the value. So if I take one of the problematic keys and ask my interpreter what its value is I get what you see. If I `print` it, however, I see the required Japanese characters:

```
>>> u'\u77ed\u9283'
u'\u77ed\u9283'
>>> print u'\u77ed\u9283'
短銃
```

So you do have the values you need, you just didn't understand that the interpreter was using a different representation, guaranteed to be representable in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. However, when I set `labels=dict_index.keys()` for the function `plot_dendrogram`, the plot cannot show the words. This is why I am trying to convert the unicode to Japanese terms or keep it unchanged when I create the dictionary.